# How to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a measurement such that the signal-to-noise ratio is a specific value?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

Consider the following measurements of the heat-producing capacity of the coal produced by a mine (in millions of calories per ton):

6260, 6130, 6750, 6370, 6340, 63212

To generate the noise of the measurement, I used the **numpy.random.normal(mean, stdefv, size)** in Python. To get the same randomly generated numbers each time I run the code, I made use of **numpy.random.normal(seed)**.

I calculated the signal using:

signal = measurement data + |noise|

So, the SNR is signal/noise.

However, I am struggling to find an appropriate mean and standard deviation such that the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) of **each** measurement is 100. I tried to adjust the mean and standard deviation to get the desired ratio for each measurement but it's either I get values way less or more than 100.

Is there a formula or equation I can use to get the desired SNR?

Your kind assistance will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**When you draw noise from a normal distribution** you get a different value each time, hence you can't have the same SNR for each measurement, nor is it what you would encounter in real life (unless you have constant signal/noise ratio as far as your instruments can measure them).

If **"the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) of each measurement is 100"** then the noise is no longer random, it's completely determined by the signal from each measurement and is something you can easily add programmatically (for each measurement: Pnoise = Psignal / SNR)

**What you might want to consider is the average SNR across your measurements**:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio
[image]

- **E[S^2]** represents the expected value of your signal
- **E[N^2]** represents the noise squared standard deviation/variance

So if you calculate **E[S^2]** from your measurements, then you have **E[N^2]**=**E[S^2]/SNR** (plug whatever SNR you want). You can then sample your noise from a normal distribution with the corresponding variance (**E[N^2]**) and mean=0 (usual case for noise). The SNR will vary for each measurement, however overall when you average the SNR over all your measurements you will get your desired SNR.

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for your answer, much appreciated. In my question, I did mention that I am using numpy.random.seed(integer), so I will get the same random numbers from the normal distribution each time I run the code. I wanted to know if there's anyway I could make the SNR for each measurement equal to 10 (or  close to 10) that involves adjusting the mean and standard deviation of the normal distribution, e.g., SNRs = (9.899, 10.045, 9.797, 9.643, 10.127, 9.9974)?

Comment: Regardless of seeding, the point of sampling from a normal dist. is to get random values (their average will converge towards the mean of the dist. but each value will differ from it, hence why you can't guarantee any particular SNR for each sample). Once again, if all you want is produce the same SNR for each measurement, that means your noise is completed determined by your signal, so forget sampling a normal dist. for your noise, just take your numpy array of signals, divide it by the desired SNR, and you get a new array of noises with the desired values.